# Json.Net CustomSerialization

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I am serializing a collection of objects that contains a dictionary called dynamic properties.

The default Json emitted looks like this:

```
[{"dynamicProperties":{"WatchId":7771,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"x","Location":"Equinix Source","Name":"PI_5570_5580"}},
{"dynamicProperties":{"WatchId":7769,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"x","Location":"Equinix Source","Name":"PI_5570_5574"}},
{"dynamicProperties":{"WatchId":7767,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"x","Location":"Equinix Source","Name":"PI_5570_5572"}},
{"dynamicProperties":{"WatchId":7765,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"y","Location":"Equinix Source","Name":"highlight_SM"}},
{"dynamicProperties":{"WatchId":8432,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"y","Location":"Test Devices","Name":"Cisco1700PI"}}]
```

I'd like to produce Json that looks like this:

```
[{"WatchId":7771,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"x","Location":"Equinix Source","Name":"PI_5570_5580"},
{"WatchId":7769,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"x","Location":"Equinix Source","Name":"PI_5570_5574"},
{"WatchId":7767,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"x","Location":"Equinix Source","Name":"PI_5570_5572"},
{"WatchId":7765,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"y","Location":"Equinix Source","Name":"highlight_SM"},
{"WatchId":8432,"Issues":0,"WatchType":"y","Location":"Test Devices","Name":"Cisco1700PI"}]
```

From reading the Json.Net documentation it looks like I could build a CustomContractResolver for my class, but I cannot find any details on how to go about this... Can anyone shed any light on the direction I should be looking in?

The class I am trying to serialize is below.

I needed a class that allow dynamic style behaviour and is also serializable and deserializable over WCF.

```
 [DataContract]
public class SerializableDynamicObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    [DataMember]
    private IDictionary<string, object> dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    #region IDynamicMetaObjectProvider implementation
    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression expression)
    {
        return new SerializableDynamicMetaObject(expression,
            BindingRestrictions.GetInstanceRestriction(expression, this), this);
    }
    #endregion



    #region Helper methods for dynamic meta object support
    internal object setValue(string name, object value)
    {
        dynamicProperties.Add(name, value);
        return value;
    }

    internal object getValue(string name)
    {
        object value;
        if (!dynamicProperties.TryGetValue(name, out value))
        {
            value = null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<string> getDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return dynamicProperties.Keys;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Could you show your serialization code?

Comment: Updated to include class to serialize

Answer (score -1):

Implement ISerializable

```
[DataContract]
public class SerializableDynamicObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, ISerializable
{
    [DataMember]
    private IDictionary<string, object> dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    #region IDynamicMetaObjectProvider implementation
    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression expression)
    {
        return new SerializableDynamicMetaObject(expression,
            BindingRestrictions.GetInstanceRestriction(expression, this), this);
    }
    #endregion



    #region Helper methods for dynamic meta object support
    internal object setValue(string name, object value)
    {
        dynamicProperties.Add(name, value);
        return value;
    }

    internal object getValue(string name)
    {
        object value;
        if (!dynamicProperties.TryGetValue(name, out value))
        {
            value = null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<string> getDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return dynamicProperties.Keys;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ISerializable Members

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (var key in dynamicProperties.Keys)
        {
            info.AddValue(key.ToString(), dynamicProperties[key]);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now test this code in a little console app...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerializableDynamicObject obj1 = new SerializableDynamicObject();
        obj1.setValue("WatchId", 7771);
        obj1.setValue("Issues", 0);
        obj1.setValue("Location", "sample location1");
        obj1.setValue("Name", "sample name 1");

        SerializableDynamicObject obj2 = new SerializableDynamicObject();
        obj2.setValue("WatchId", 7771);
        obj2.setValue("Issues", 0);
        obj2.setValue("Location", "sample location1");
        obj2.setValue("Name", "sample name 1");

        SerializableDynamicObject obj3 = new SerializableDynamicObject();
        obj3.setValue("WatchId", 7771);
        obj3.setValue("Issues", 0);
        obj3.setValue("Location", "sample location1");
        obj3.setValue("Name", "sample name 1");

        SerializableDynamicObject[] dictArray = new
        SerializableDynamicObject[] { 
            obj1, obj2, obj3
        };

        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer ser = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, dictArray);
}
```

This is the output of the program:

[{"WatchId":7771,"Issues":0,"Location":"sample location1","Name":"sample name 1"},{"WatchId":7771,"Issues":0,"Location":"sample location2","Name":"sample name 2"},{"WatchId":7771,"Issues":0,"Location":"sample location3","Name":"sample name3"}]

Comment: I can't change the structure of the class - I just need to control how it's serialized

Comment: Then just implement ISerializable on the class declaration of SerializableDynamicObject and you'll get results you need.

Comment: That does allow serialization to work, but it fails to deserialize when sent across WCF.